# Ball vs Ball collision Optimization

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

I'm working on a project that has balls colliding, The way I detect this collision is simple. It takes an object from the array and then compares itself with all the objects in the array. How collision is detected is by checking if the center point distance is lower than the two radius's.

This works great but when you have 100 plus objects at the same time, there is a lot of redundancy. Meaning why would a single object check for the position of an object on the other side of the screen, where the chances of it colliding are low.

I found a theory on this that an object should check only other objects in an area larger than itself. Then if there is another object in that area, detecting collision would start. But this just creates extra checks since the object has to check all objects if it's in the area and then check if the object is colliding.

Is there a method to efficiently detect collision?

```
public function newHandler():void
{
    for ( var i:int = 0; i < _objectArrayLayer1.length; i++ )
    {
        mcBall1 = _objectArrayLayer1[i];

            for ( var j:int = i + 1; j < _objectArrayLayer1.length; j++)
            {
                mcBall2 = _objectArrayLayer1[j];

                p1 = new Point(mcBall1.nX, mcBall1.nY);
                p2 = new Point(mcBall2.nX, mcBall2.nY);
                distance = Point.distance(p1,p2);

                radius1 = mcBall1._radius ;
                radius2 = mcBall2._radius ;

                if (distance <= radius1 + radius2)
                {
                    solveBalls( mcBall1, mcBall2 );
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you can do to speed up your loop - this is not a definitive list but it'll help gain a bit of extra performance.

1. You're creating a lot of temporary `Point` objects for your checks. Just create 2 `Point` objects at the beginning of the function and keep updating their `x` and `y` coordinates. This way you'll avoid the cost of constructing a lot of objects. Memory allocation is expensive and then the garbage collector will also have to deal with them.
2. You should cache `mcBall1._radius` in a local variable (like `radius1` - it's faster than reading the property in every iteration of the nested loop.
3. Instead of using `distance`, use the square of the distance - this way you avoid calculating a square root. In this case you can cache `radius1*radius1`.

In addition to these, you can partition your world into sections and assign a partition index to each of them. Add a partition variable to each of the balls - as they move across the world, you'll update this partition variable. This is not an expensive operation since it's just a simple check to see if the ball is within which partition rectangle - depending on the speed of the balls, they can only move to so many other partitions from a given partition.

If you use a 5x5 partitioning that gives you 25 partitions and at any time you'll know how many balls are within a single partition. When it comes to collision detection, you can avoid checking any objects that are not in the current partition or in any of the surrouinding partitions. This will give your collision detection code a noticable boost.

Look at this question for an example: [Optimizing collison detection code in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995529/optimizing-collison-detection-code-in-as3)

**Edit**: while I was typing, @Paddyd posted his answer of quad trees - this is really a simple implementation of a "quadtree" but with no nested partitions and 5x5 instead of 2x2 partitions.

Comment: `Point.distance` adds yet another point, OP will indeed be better with squaring X offset and Y offset and comparing with square of sum of radii. Otherwise, good.

Comment: @Vesper `Point.distance` doesn't create a `Point` object - it returns a `Number`. It'd probably be faster to calculate just the square of the distance locally (not in a function call).

Comment: Ow. Sorry, seems that I've got to sleep.

Comment: For point 1 you are right, but the second point I have to check for the radius each loop because the objects have different sizes. The third point, I have tried that before and it slowed lowered the fps. I tried it again and now it increases the performance, really weird.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll give your quadtree implementation a try.

Comment: @Banzboy Yes, you cannot cache the 2nd point. If you do the calculation locally (no function call) you don't need any `Point` objects anyway - you'll just use the `x` and `y` coordinates.

Comment: Sorry by point I mean your number 1. not the Point. I have to keep calling radius every iteration because I have to get the most recent radius.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

[Here](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space/) is an example of implementing one.